# Spring-beans DefaultListableBeanFactory - how allBeanNamesByType is populated

Tags: java, spring-bean

in spring beans class DefaultListableBeanFactory we have variable which is used inside method getBeanNamesForType. This is used as a cache. I want to understand how this is populated as in one of our application is not populating beans of the type EntityManager.

Comment: facing same issue, could not see any place where this map is getting populated :(